# trying to free nonexisting resource

Tags: linux-kernel

i am writing network driver..i which i am **requesting memory region** during insertion i dont face any problem, infact i dont get any error.. but when i remove the module i get error `"trying to free nonexisting resource <00000000000 - 00000000007>"`

a snippet of my code is here,
am doing this in init module..

```
request_mem_region(BASE_addr + ETH1 + TSEC_CRG1, 8 , "TSEC_CRG1");
    printk("ioadd request region =  %p\n",ioadd);
```

and clean

```
release_mem_region(BASE_addr + ETH1 + TSEC_CRG1, 8 , "TSEC_CRG1");
```

can anyone help me sort this error...

Comment: What is value of `ioadd`? Why don't you use it for `request`/`release_mem_region`? And MMIO is not memory.

Comment: `release_mem_region` takes only two parameters...